# What is the way to share data between sites in a multisite

Tags: multisite, rest-api, switch-to-blog

We want to display the same data on multiple sites in a multisite. This data needs to be added/edited by the client.

We can create a custom post type and use the switch_to_blog function to get the right data on each site. But isn't there a better solution?

Maybe a custom table where we save the data and get the data from. Or using the REST API to get the data from a blog or the custom table.

What would be the best solution also performance wise?

Comment: This is too general. What kind of data? How much data? For example there are network wide option values that can be made with update_site_option() and accessed with get_site_option().

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

It are courses, which will be added with a custom post type. And needs to be updated on regular basis and there will be added more courses in the future.

So using a custom post type looks like the best way. But don't know what performance and logical wise the smart move is about saving the data. Or in a custom table or in the main site and getting the data from there.

Comment: There is no way of doing any kind of global posts that I know of. I think I would do it with my own global database table that all sites can then access with database queries directly.

Comment: A simple possibility may be using an RSS feed approach?   The secondary sites use the feed from the main site ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin from 10up called Distributor that is set up to do this now. See https://distributorplugin.com/. I have gotten it to work for a custom post type but it did not transfer the map data associated with it from the WP Maps Pro. I may be missing something with that, though, as I am fairly new to WP.